# What are the points which keep in mind while using Multidimensional or Jagged array while working for better performance?

Tags: arrays

What are the points which keep in mind while using Multidimensional or Jagged array while working for better performance ?
I don't want comparison ,i am asking in tearms of best ways to work on these array like sort or updating or cloning?

Thanks in advance